# Oracle SQL Check current rows with previous rows dynamically

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to work on something in Oracle SQL in the attached table.
[image]

The goal is to define a Visit Type where a Primary Visit refers to any visits that happened after 3 months from previous visit(s). However, the challenge is that sometimes I'll need to compare to previous row and sometimes I need to compare with previous N rows.

For e.g., Transaction ID 3 is a revisit because its start date is within the 'end date +90 days' of Transaction ID 1 (Dec 16). Transaction ID 4 is primary because it happened after it took place after the the very first 'end date+90 days', meaning I not only need to compare to previous 1 row but previous 3 rows.

Hope this is clear!

Thanks.

See Details above. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12 you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT transaction_id, start_date, end_date, visit_type
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY start_date
  MEASURES
    CLASSIFIER() AS visit_type
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (PRIMARY revisit*)
  DEFINE revisit AS start_date <= FIRST(end_date) + INTERVAL '90' DAY 
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (transaction_id, start_date, end_date) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-08-05', DATE '2020-09-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-09-19', DATE '2020-10-27' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2020-11-01', DATE '2020-12-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2021-01-23', DATE '2021-01-26' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, DATE '2021-02-27', DATE '2021-03-27' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TRANSACTION_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | VISIT_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-08-05 00:00:00 | 2020-09-07 00:00:00 | PRIMARY |
| 2 | 2020-09-19 00:00:00 | 2020-10-27 00:00:00 | REVISIT |
| 3 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | 2020-12-19 00:00:00 | REVISIT |
| 4 | 2021-01-23 00:00:00 | 2021-01-26 00:00:00 | PRIMARY |
| 5 | 2021-02-27 00:00:00 | 2021-03-27 00:00:00 | REVISIT |

Comment: Do we need to DEFINE what a PRIMARY is as well ?

Comment: @user13617491 No, `PRIMARY` matches anything so it does not need to be defined. If you wanted to do so for completeness then you can use `DEFINE primary AS 1 = 1, revisit AS ...` but it is not necessary.